# Best 3D software / library to develop an interactive 3D editor.

Tags: library, framework, 3d

I need to develop a kind of Paint, only for 3D. The main feature of the program is an ability to "draw" 3D models in 3D space.

I have a permission to use any package / tool / library I choose, including commercial products. Main platform is Windows, and it should be a desktop application. It could be in C++, C#, or Java.

I have much 3D programming experience in DirectX/Direct3D, OpenGL, Java3D, Helix Toolkit etc. However all the libraries/SDKs that I know are lacking this very important interactive drawing feature "right out of the box".
I am not familiar with Unity or Unreal, do they have this option? Are there other libraries better suited for my purpose? What would be the best tool for the task if taking a learning curve into consideration?

Comment: So isn´t Paint 3D exactly what you want?

Comment: @convert AFAIK Paint3D is not a library, neither IDE ))

Answer (score -1):

[Blender](https://www.blender.org/)

Admittedly, blender has a significant learning curve.  However, it has a built-in scripting language you can use to adapt it.

Alternatively,  Being a novice and trying to build a 3d house from scratch, I also have use sketchup from http://www.sketchup.com  After watching only a few short videos I was ready to go, and built the 3d model of a house.

Comment: I am not trying to prebuild a 3D model, I am trying to create and manipulate it in the realtime, on the fly.

Comment: @Flot2011: how do you want to draw in 3D? Do you have a 3D pen or 3D gloves or some other special 3D painting hardware? AFAIK, one does not draw in 3D, one models in 3D. Blender even has sculping tools which work like a brush that increases volume or decreases volume.

Comment: @cybernard: the tool is ok, but IMHO the answer is not. It does not explain how it fulfills the needs of the OP

Comment: @ThomasWeller I was looking for a digital sculpting library, allowing to manipulate a model  (pinch, cut, fold etc.) using a regular mouse. BTW it is still actual if you have some advice.